# how to read from a file and append it to the end of another file in c++

Tags: c++

I opened two files and I want to find the most efficient way to put data from out file to in fill.
I tried `rdbuf()` but it doesn't work and the outfile is the same so I need to have more explanation for `rdbuf()` and is there another method to append a file to another?

```
ofstream writeto;
writeto.open(srr.c_str(),ios::app);
cout<<"give me the file you want to copy from  : ";
string written;
cin>>written;
ifstream writefrom;
writefrom.open(written.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to copy the entire input file:

```
writeto << writefrom.rdbuf();
```

Also, you should use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>` so you can account for file path/names that have space characters in them:

```
getline(cin, written);
```

Comment: i tried writefrom.rdbuf() but the file don't change so i asked   here to  get another answer or to know why this don't work

Comment: `std::ofstream` has an `operator<<` that takes a `std::basic_streambuf*` as input. `std::ifstream::rdbuf()` returns a `std::basic_filebuf*`, and `std::basic_filebuf` derives from `std::basic_streambuf`, so it should work. Did you verify that `writeto.open()` and `writefrom.open()` are both successful?  There is no error handling in the code you showed.

Answer (score -2):

Read a file into a stream object, read the next file into the stream. Write out the stream.